# jQuery not working internal pages

Tags: jquery

Okay, weirdest thing and I can't work it out.

I installed (and purchased) the plugin Seed Pro Coming Soon and built my site. Looks great!

However as soon as I disable this plugin and view my site I get a bunch of errors such as:

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

And nothing jQuery related on my internal pages work. Everything on my homepage works perfectly, but any pages inside don't.

Huh? Does anyone have any clues? I need to launch this site and not even the dropdown menu will work!

Answer (score -1):

Managed to fix it by adding this to the header.php file:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't add it directly in to the head instead enqueue jQuery that is bundled with WP using `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: And what is bad about the way i'm doing it? It seems to work?